# How can My GUI appear when my noob is killed?

Tags: lua, roblox

```
[My code is :]

local function MWin()
game.StarterGui.ScreenGui1.DemonWin.Visible = true
if game.Workspace.Mages_Boss.Humanoid.Died:connect(function()
print("good")
end
```

[My noob is named : Mages_Boss
And my screen gui is named : DemonWin
I dont know what to put for "print("good")".]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, modifying the starter GUI does nothing. You need to change the one player or all players with a for loop. In my answer, I’ll use the former with a player named ROBLOX.  If you want to start with it invisible, you need `game.Players.ROBLOX.PlayerGui.ScreenGui1.DemonWin.Visible = false`. To make it visible on the death event, use `game.Players.ROBLOX.PlayerGui.ScreenGui1.DemonWin.Visible = true`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
DemonWin.Enabled=true;
```

or

```
DemonWin.Enabled=false;
```

to toggle whether it is active or not. I suppose in the died function, use the latter.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to assume you're not firing the function so you can get rid of that. You're also going to remove the `.Died` since it fires even when it's not dead. So your best bet would be to do also add a debounce- kind of function to your script. Here's the modified version:

```
game.StarterGui.ScreenGui1.DemonWin.Visible = false
    if game.Workspace.Mages_Boss.Humanoid.Health == 0 then
    game.StarterGui.ScreenGui1.DemonWin.Visible = true
    else
game.StarterGui.ScreenGui1.DemonWin.Visible = false
end
```

Also, you would have to put the GUI in the StarterGui (located in `game.Players.LocalPlayer.StarterGui`) in order to not publicly malfunction this script.